# Interpreting Atmega328p data sheet

Tags: c, arduino, avr

I'm trying to program an Arduino Uno with AVR code because I'm not allowed to use the Arduino libraries for my senior project that starts in September.  I found the data sheet, got the digital pins working, and moved on to trying to talk to my computer through the USB Serial connection.  I've read chapter 19 of this manual ([1](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf)) entirely too many times, and I am still lost.  I copy and pasted code from the library documentation itself and the data sheet, and it still says things are unresolved and/or not found.  Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h>

#define analog1 PC0
#define LED PB5
#define BAUD 9600
//#define F_CPU 16000000

void init_io(){
    DDRB |= (1<<LED);
    DDRC |= (0<<analog1);

}

static void
   uart_9600(void)
    {
   UBRRH = UBRRH_VALUE;
   UBRRL = UBRRL_VALUE;
   #if USE_2X
   UCSRA |= (1 << U2X);
   #else
   UCSRA &= ~(1 << U2X);
   #endif
   }

void USART_Transmit( unsigned char data )
{
/* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
while ( !( UCSRnA & (1<<UDREn)) )
;
/* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
UDRn= data;
}

int main(){
    int analog_value = 1000;
    while(1){
        //analog_value = PINC;

        if(analog_value > 500){
            PORTB |= (1<<LED);
            _delay_ms(500);
            PORTB &= ~(1<<LED);
            _delay_ms(500);
            putchar(analog_value);

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Provide more detail about what you dont understand or what is not working.

Comment: Usually the `n` denotes a number of your port. So if you're using `USART0` then use `UCSR0A`, `UDRE0` and `UDR0 = data`. Still, you haven't made it clear what you need help with. Can you please elaborate on the problem?

Comment: Similarly, you're not actually transmitting anything in your `main` function... Is the transmission happening on an interrupt?

Comment: I've tried replacing the n with a 0, still get errors.  And the ones that show up as not found are UBRRH = UBRRH_VALUE;
   UBRRL = UBRRL_VALUE;    UCSRA |= (1 << U2X);     while ( !( UCSRnA & (1<<UDREn)) )      UDRn= data;    I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Where did you even find code with UBRRH and UBRRL? The atmega328 doesn't even have those registers (which would explain why the compiler complains they are not found)

Comment: If you provide us the actual errors you're getting from the compiler, that will help direct our answers...

Comment: From setbaud.h:                                                           Example usage:

   \code
   #include <avr/io.h>

   #define F_CPU 4000000

   static void
   uart_9600(void)
   {
   #define BAUD 9600
   #include <util/setbaud.h>
   UBRRH = UBRRH_VALUE;
   UBRRL = UBRRL_VALUE;
   #if USE_2X
   UCSRA |= (1 << U2X);
   #else
   UCSRA &= ~(1 << U2X);
   #endif
   }

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - ‘UDRE’ was not declared in this scope
 - ‘UCSRA’ was not declared in this 
  scope
 - Symbol 'UDRE0' could not be 
  resolved
 - Symbol 'UCSR0A' could not be 
  resolved

Answer (score 1):

The first issue you have in your code is the AVR-libc one. You are using the `util/setbaud.h` file incorrectly. I suggest you take a look at the documentation [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__setbaud.html). To make things brief, you need to `#define BAUD 9600` **before** you `#include <util/setbaud.h>`. Then, as others have pointed out, your register names are incorrect. The USART control registers are `UCSRnA`, `UCSRnB` and `UCSRnC`; the baud registers are `UBRRnL` and `UBRRnH`, where `n` is the number of the serial port in use on the device, indexed from 0.

You also need to define a function to handle `stdout`, as AVR-libc provides you none. See the documentation for [`stdio.h`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html) in order to learn how to write one.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? How am I am using it wrong?  How do I know which serial port to use?